# Sails.js - Encrypt password

Tags: sails.js

For a project, I need to have users and i want to stock an encrypted password in the database.

So I need your help because i need to encrypt password when I add an user, but I have an error into the terminal when I launch `sails lift`:

```
In model `user`:
The `toJSON` instance method is no longer supported.
Instead, please use the `customToJSON` model setting.
```

Configuration:

I'm using the `Sails 1.0 Beta` and `Bcrypt 1.0.2`.

Model User.js

```
/**
* User.js
*
* @description :: A model definition.  Represents a database 
table/collection/etc.
* @docs        :: https://sailsjs.com/docs/concepts/models-and-
orm/models
*/

var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');


module.exports = {


attributes: {
    firstname: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    lastname: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    password: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    email: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true
    },
    code: {
        type: 'string',
        unique: true
    },
    referring: {
        type: 'string'
    },
    comment: {
        type: 'text'
    },
    // Add reference to Profil
    profil: {
        model: 'profil'
    },
    toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        return obj;
    }
},
beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                cb(err);
            } else {
                user.password = hash;
                cb();
            }
        });
    });
}
};
```

I think I'm using an old way to encrypt the password, but I don't know or don't find an another way to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `bcrypt` is not encryption, it is just badly named. It is  cryptographic hashing method designed for passwords that includes substantial CPU computational time, it is a secure method. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Answer (score 2):

I think You should do the following and remember put this customToJSON function after the `attributes:{...},`

```
attributes:{...},

customToJSON: function() {
  // Return a shallow copy of this record with the password and ssn removed.
  return _.omit(this, ['password'])
}
```

[Chek out from this link](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?customtojson)

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question is old, but hopfully this will shed some light.

As of Sails 1.0, instance methods are no longer supported. The documentation suggests that you should use `customToJSON` instead, but it doesn't clarify that you should use it outside of the attributes.

customToJSON allows you to stringify the data with a custom function before sending it.
In your case, you'll want to omit the password.
With customToJSON you can use the `this` keyword to access the returned object. It's advised not to mutate this object, intsead create a copy.

So for your example you'd use:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {...},

  customToJSON: function() {
    return _.omit(this, ['password'])
  },

  beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {...}

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you see has nothing to do with the encryption. Look in your model and take note of the toJSON function. As the error message indicates, this is an instance method and it is no longer supported. So do as suggested: use the `customToJSON` model setting. I am sure you will find it in the documentation.